# Why websocket protocol uses a different response code than http

Tags: websocket

I was wondering why websocket protocol  did not use ( say the designers did not choose)  the same response code of http ( like 200,404 or 403 ) etc to convey the response  ?  Instead there are 101 which means the communication is established.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The main reason is that 101 "Switching Protocols" is a legal HTTP response code, and indicates that the conversation is not finished yet very clearly.  I say that because a 1xx code is not a success code (2xx), redirect (3xx) or error code (4xx) or server error (5xx).

It seems that the relatively unknown 101 "Switching Protocols" was built in to HTTP in anticipation of negotiating other protocols.  WebSocket is one such protocol that has been formalized using that mechanism.

This offers a rather clean way to separate the HTTP conversation upfront (allowing traversal of proxies/intermediaries over open ports on the Internet) from the WebSocket conversation afterwards.  The neat trick is that we then can start a bi-directional WebSocket conversation using the connection established over HTTP; this gives WebSockets a more universal appeal by being as reliable to establish as HTTP connections over the open Internet.

Answer (score 0):

WebSocket is a separate protocol from HTTP.  The 101 response is actually "Switching Protocols".
http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html